# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 GRPC error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After I upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, the logcat tab in the Android Studio don't work properly. It continuously output the following error log. I don't know what's wrong.

> 05-19 18:05:18.676 10029-10072/com.example.chansoncc.bodypractice E/GRPC: tcp_client_posix.c:176] failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:12389': socket error: connection refused

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is `com.example.chansoncc.bodypractice`? is it yours?

Comment: i get the same error in the logs.that is his package name.

Comment: I get this also - doesn't appear in release mode, so perhaps something to do with the new data collection stuff, network calls and profiling etc?

Comment: @pskink
`com.example.chansoncc.bodypractice` is my example package

Comment: HMM SURE IS INTERESTING STACK OVERFLOW... I posted this exact same question a few months ago, worded almost identically to this and I got 3 down-votes saying my question didn't provide enough information! I posted the error just like Chanson here along with MORE information trying to pin-point the issue. Now that others have the issue it is ok to ask? I am glad to see there is a fix for this because the issue came back for me today, but I really don't understand why I was down-voted.

Answer (score 19):

Workaround is to start `Android Profiler`.

Comment: OP did not ask a question, they asked for help. Outofdate provided help. Real solution will be to wait for the Android Studio devs to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem (at this time)

1. Start an **Android Profiler** as [Outofdate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3232379/outofdate) suggested
2. Go to **Run > Edit Configurations..**, select the app then click on profiling tab. Make sure that **Enable advanced profiling** is off